# Ruby: Use condition result in condition block

Tags: ruby, regex

I have such code

```
reg = /(.+)_path/
if reg.match('home_path')
    puts reg.match('home_path')[0]
end
```

This will eval regex twice :(
So...

```
reg = /(.+)_path/
result = reg.match('home_path')
if result
    puts result[0]
end
```

But it will store variable result in memory till.
I have one functional-programming idea

```
/(.+)_path/.match('home_path').compact.each do |match|
    puts match[0]
end
```

But seems there should be better solution, isn't it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are special global variables (their names start with `$`) that contain results of the last regexp match:

```
r = /(.+)_path/

# $1 - the n-th group of the last successful match (may be > 1)
puts $1 if r.match('home_path')
# => home 

# $& - the string matched by the last successful match
puts $& if r.match('home_path')
# => home_path
```

You can find full list of predefined global variables [here](http://www.zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html#19).

Note, that in the examples above `puts` won't be executed at all if you pass a string that doesn't match the regexp.

And speaking about general case you can always put assignment into condition itself:

```
if m = /(.+)_path/.match('home_path')
  puts m[0]
end
```

Though, many people don't like that as it makes code less readable and gives a good opportunity for confusing `=` and `==`.

Answer (score 6):

My personal favorite (w/ 1.9+) is some variation of:

```
if /(?<prefix>.+)_path/ =~ "home_path"
   puts prefix
end
```

If you really want a one-liner: `puts /(?<prefix>.+)_path/ =~ 'home_path' ? prefix : false`

See the [Ruby Docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-7E) for a few limitations of named captures and  `#=~`.

Comment: I still can't decide whether I like that feature or not. It silently overrides local variables that sound pretty dangerous to me. And speaking of one-liners interpreter doesn't allow you to do `puts m if /(?<m>.+)/ =~ 'qwe'` (if `m` wasn't previously defined) that would be a bit nicer.

Comment: It does spit out a warning, but I never run w/ warnings. Anyway, thanks for showing, I didn't know about this feature.

Comment: @zeke https://gist.github.com/1525394

The warning is "named capture conflicts a local variable - prefix" on the line with the match.

Comment: @JoshuaCheek Gotcha. There's no real need to set `prefix = nil` before the conditional. No match, means `prefix = nil` anyway. In the more common context of a Ruby method (see: https://gist.github.com/1525397) the local variable problem is minimized a great deal.

Comment: @zeke the reason I define `prefix = nil` before the block is to simulate the situation where the matcher overrides a local variable. This is what causes the warning to be invoked (a counter-example to @KL-7's complaint that "It silently overrides local variables").

Beyond that, the single line version `puts prefix if /(?<prefix>.+)_path/ =~ "home_path"` will work if the var is already defined, but will raise a `NameError` otherwise.

Comment: @JoshuaCheek, thanks, now I know that you have to turn on warnings explicitly in ruby.

Answer (score 6):

From the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-i-match): *If a block is given, invoke the block with MatchData if match succeed*.

So:

```
/(.+)_path/.match('home_path') { |m| puts m[1] }  # => home

/(.+)_path/.match('homepath') { |m| puts m[1] }  # prints nothing
```

Answer (score 2):

How about...

```
if m=/regex here/.match(string) then puts m[0] end
```

A neat one-line solution, I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

how about this ?

```
puts $~ if /regex/.match("string")
```

`$~` is a special variable that stores the last regexp match. more info: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this can be done with no conditionals at all. (The expression evaluates to `""` if there is no match.)

```
puts /(.+)_path/.match('home_xath').to_a[0].to_s
```

Comment: But `puts x if x` isn't quite equivalent to `puts x.to_s` when `x.nil?`, `puts x.to_s` produces a newline whereas `puts x if x` won't.